# mysql SELECT query with multiple joins requiring latest table data

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have a mysql query which links 3 tables together by product_id.

```
SELECT 
P.product_id, P.title, P.unit,
Pp.date, Pp.price, Pp.wasprice,
C.quantity, C.date_added
FROM productdetail P

INNER JOIN
productprices Pp
ON P.product_id = Pp.product_id

RIGHT JOIN
cart C
ON Pp.product_id = C.product_id
WHERE C.session = :session AND C.quantity > 0
```

If one or more entries have been made into the **table productprices** this query will provide all dates. I only require the latest entry for each product_id. Therefore in the fiddle below it should result in 3 different items all with the latest date.

I have created a **[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ca3d/1/0)** to show you what I mean, and to make it easier for you to edit. I have tried sub queries but all to no avail.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest `date` for every `product_id` inside a subquery and the result is join on table `productdetail`

eg.

```
SELECT 
P.product_id, P.title,
Pp.date, Pp.price,
C.quantity, C.date_added
FROM
productdetail P
INNER JOIN
productprices Pp
ON P.product_id = Pp.product_id     
INNER JOIN

(
  SELECT product_id, MAX(date) AS max_date      -- << this part will get the latest row
  FROM productprices                            -- << in every product_id
  GROUP BY product_id
) maxx 
ON Pp.product_id = maxx.product_id 

AND Pp.date = maxx.max_date
RIGHT JOIN
cart C
ON Pp.product_id = C.product_id
WHERE C.session = 12345 AND C.quantity > 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ca3d/3)

Comment: Thanks John, I had no idea where to start in regards to the sub-query. But the way you have put the answer makes it a lot clearer. Cheers :)